# Objective C code equal to $.post method in jquery

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, nsurl

Hi am new to Objective C i am developing an iOS app which sends the request to a REST API and get authenticated to perform action like getting json/xml response.

If we send request it will give a session token as response which keeps me authenticated  for a while.

Below code work like a charm in browser but i don't know how to reproduce in Objective C language where i should able to store the token so that to keep me authenticated. Kindly anyone help me out in this .Thanks in advance. :)

```
$.post( 
    url, {
        username:'xyz', 
        password:'123'
        })
    .done(function() {
        #success alert
    })
    .always(function( data ) { 
        #always alert
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use and `NSURLRequest`:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData* body = [@"{username:'xyz', password:'123'}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setURL:url];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

NSString* responseJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason for the reply but the when i use this code it is showing the content of the of the page.Not the token. Its showing as if we enter the url in browser and in response it is giving me the content.

Comment: If we straight away give the url in the website it will showing "Unauthorized access" but when we send them through jquery post method it will give me token back. In this case it is showing "Unauthorized access" when i try the above code.

Comment: Are you posting form data? If so, get rid of the application/json line.